# Concurrent Multi browsers testing

Tags: selenium, browser, concurrency, cross-browser, geb

We are using Geb, Gradle, spock and Jenkins for UI testing,
I was wondering what would be the best approach to run the all test suite concurrently on all the test browsers? 
1. Configure it as part of the gradle build?
or
2. Create a multi project axis in Jenkins for every browser/os?

10x

Comment: Are you trying to execute this all one one machine or across a CI on multiple nodes?